# Software to automate your FTP downloads

Tags: windows-7, windows, ftp, download

How can I automate my FTP downloads and remotely check the status of my downloads? Is there a way that can be done by some software? Or, is it possible that a software can email (and shutdown) my laptop once the downloads are done.

Comment: What do you want to automate? What problem are you trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: I want to auto-downloads the files when I am not home and want to have a some sort of scheduler that can start the downloads based on a specific time and can download the particular files. In fact I found one software i.e. DeskShare Auto FTP Manager 7 but it crashes everytime I open the s/w to use it

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to limit number of simultaneous connections?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [WinScp Scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

[Martin Prikryl](https://superuser.com/users/213663/martin-prikryl)`s  tool [WinScp](https://winscp.net) is a sort of *Swiss Army Knife* for file transfer, and his website shines with numerous examples regarding [scheduling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule) and [mail confirmation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#results).

Using Windows tasks, you could automatically start [WinScp](https://winscp.net) scripts.

The same - with fewer features - could be attempted with the Windows standard [FTP client](https://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/using-built-windows-ftp-client) executing [FTP take files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936227/1911064).

There are lots of [tools available](https://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/) to send the confirmation mail from a Windows PC.

The [shutdown command](https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/shutdown-power-off-windows-10-using-cmd.html) can be finally used to power-off the PC.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: You have a point there, but the text should contain enough keywords to find relevant examples rather quickly.

Comment: See also WinSCP article [Emailing script results](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_email).